# Given a real world dataset of film budgets and their actual gross profit, find the optimal budget

Tags: calculus

So I am currently working on a project for a Data Science Bootcamp that I started about a month ago and we are examining the film industry to gleam certain insights that we determine. What I am looking to do is take this dataset that I have compiled that involves the budget of the film and the domestic/international gross of the film and return what the optimal budget to make the most profit is. I have been googling and I am not certain what to google to get an answer. I have found several bits of information that gives me a feeling I am heading in the right direction, but I can't seem to find exactly what I am looking for. This is probably something simple that I am just overlooking, but I am having a difficult time finding it. Though I have a sneaking suspicion that this may be a linear regression problem.

A huge plus if you can also relate it to a way I could graph it to determine this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In mathematical terms, you have an independent variable $X_i$, the cost of producing film $i$; and a dependent variable $Y_i$, the percentage profit realised by film $i$ (percentage profit is probably more relevant than absolute profit - it is better to spend ten million dollars on ten $1$ million dollar films that make a profit of half a million dollars each than on one ten million dollar film that makes a profit of two million dollars).

You now need a statistical model which connects the dependent and independent variables:

$Y_i = f(X_i, \beta_0, \beta_1 \dots ) + \epsilon_i$

where $f$ is your predictor function, $\beta_0, \beta_1$ etc. are parameters and $\epsilon_i$ is an error term. For example, in a linear model you would have a linear predictor function

$f= \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_i$

You can then use your data to estimate the values of your model parameters that best fit your model to the data, and you can get an objective measure of how good that fit is. If you are using a linear model then the right tool for the job is [linear regression analysis](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression), but a non-linear model will need some other type of [regression analysis](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_analysis).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It makes a lot of sense when you sort of spell it out like that. I had a sneaking suspicion that this may require some sort of regression analysis from my limited understanding of the what and how of regression analysis.